# Save Passwords in Ubuntu-Touch Brower

Tags: ubuntu-touch, password, default-browser

I am looking for a way to save login details for websites on my Aquaris E5.

Does anyone know, if the default browser supports this? - I could not find anything in the preferences...

Alternatively: Is there a way to use Keepass?